# How \span influences number of `&' in \halign?

Tags: alignment

Consider this preamble:

```
\tabskip=0pt plus1fil#&#&#\tabskip=0pt
```

The last template is `#`, so it should not matter whether a line is `\BOX&\BOX&\cr` or `\BOX&\BOX\cr`. But it turns out, it does matter, but only when there is a line with `\span`. I would like to understand why the `&` before `\cr` is important. For example:

```
\def\BOX{\vrule width50pt height8.5pt depth3.5pt}

\vbox{\offinterlineskip
\halign to 16em{\tabskip=0pt plus1fil#&#&#\tabskip=0pt\cr
\BOX&\BOX&\cr
&\span\leaders\vrule height8.5pt depth3.5pt\hfill\cr
}}

\vbox{\offinterlineskip
\halign to 16em{\tabskip=0pt plus1fil#&#&#\tabskip=0pt\cr
\BOX&\BOX\cr
&\span\leaders\vrule height8.5pt depth3.5pt\hfill\cr
}}
```

For conveniency, there is a ruler. We can easily see that the second column shifts by 25pt when `&` before `\cr` is removed:

```
% ruler:
\vskip5pt
\def\\#1{\hbox to 10pt{\hfil#1}}
\def\1{\vrule height 0pt depth 2pt}
\def\2{\vrule height 0pt depth 4pt}
\def\3{\vrule height 0pt depth 8pt}
\def\4{\\\1\\\1\\\1\\\1\\\2\\\1\\\1\\\1\\\1\\\3}
\hbox to160pt{\hrulefill} \nointerlineskip
\hbox{\3\4\\\1\\\1\\\1\\\1\\\2\\\1} \nointerlineskip
\font\7=cmr7 \font\5=cmr5
\hbox to360pt{\rlap{\70}\kern50pt\rlap{\550}\kern50pt\rlap{\7100}\kern50pt
  \rlap{\5150}\hss}
```

[image]

Comment: What about `\tabskip` glue?

Comment: @egreg In the first halign we have such lines: `g0 w50 g30 w50 g30 w0 g0` and `g0 w50 g30 w50 g30 w0 g0` (here the second `w50` is an overfull box with filler glue set to 80 - the result of `\span`). In the secord halign we have such lines: `g0 w50 g55 w50 g55` and `g0 w50 g55 w50 g55 w-50 g0` and I'm completely stymied where these results come from, especially that number of boxes and glue in first line and second line are different.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the case when `&` is not used. When the second line (with `\span`) is present, we get this for the first line:

```
g0 w50 g55 w50 g55
```

when it is not present, we get this for the first line:

```
g0 w50 g30 w50 g30
```

From this we can conclude that glue is set with influence from line with `\span`. That is, glue is calculated for the second line and after that this glue is used for the first line.

Here is the second line:

```
...\hbox(8.5+3.5)x160.00024, glue set 55.00012fil
....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
....\hbox(8.5+3.5)x50.0
....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\hbox(8.5+3.5)x50.0, glue set 55.00012fill
.....\leaders 0.0 plus 1.0fill
......\rule(8.5+3.5)x0.4
....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x-50.0
....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
```

Let's use formula on p.245 of *TeXbook* to understand why widths are 50, 50 and -50:

`w_1` is `w_11` = 50. `w_2` is max from `w_12`-(`w_11`+`t_1`) and `w_22`. `w_12` is -infinity, so `w_2` is `w_22` = 50.

The thing that must be found out is why third column has width -50.

`w_3` is max from

- `w_13` - (`w_1`+`t_1`) - (`w_2`+`t_2`)
- `w_23` - (`w_2`+`t_2`)
- `w_33`

Natural width of tabskip glue is zero, so `t_k` is zero. So, `w_3` is max from

- `w_13` - `w_1` - `w_2`
- `w_23` - `w_2`
- `w_33`

There is no span from 1 to 3, so `w_13` is -infinity. So, `w_3` is max from

- `w_23` - `w_2`
- `w_33`

`w_2` is 50, so `w_3` is max from

- `w_23` - 50
- `w_33`

The value "-50" happens only in the first of these expressions, so it must be the value of `w_3`. For this `w_33` must be -infinity. And it follows that `w_23` is zero.

To sum it up: if span is done for more columns than are in other rows, TeX considers the width of the missing columns to be -infinity and width of entries that span the missing column to be zero.

To conclude: if you use `\span`, make sure that at least one of the rows has the corresponding number of `&`'s.